# Changing Firefox icon in MWM/CDE

Tags: x11, freebsd, firefox, x-resources, motif

I am trying to change the icon for Firefox using X resources and CDE. I am not sure if it is possible anymore.

I have tried this:

`Dtwm*firefox*iconImage:   Dtterm`

and this:

`Dtwm*mozilla*iconImage:   Dtterm`

in `.Xdefaults`

This way of changing the iconized image is known to work with other apps.

Is it still possible to change the icon in firefox?

I am using FreeBSD 13.2, Firefox 115.6.0esr (64-bit) and Common Desktop Environment.